# glue jupyter notebook locally instead of labs?

Tags: python, docker, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue

```
docker run -itd -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 --name glue_jupyter amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_2.0.0_image_01 /home/glue_user/jupyter/jupyter_start.sh
```

results in
[image: Docker logs]

i'm able to open 127.0.0.1:8888 and it redirects to jupyter labs
How do i go to jupyter notebook instead?

should i bash instead and then jupyter notebook from there? unsure.

Comment: cant you open a new notebook? or if you have any existing notebooks, then you can run docker from the specific folder?

Comment: @Yuva I tried to open terminal from within jupyter lab, but opening the link as mentinoed here for notebook fails https://imgur.com/a/fEMpFDC

I'm able to see jupyter lab notebook, was wondering how to open jupyter notebook. I'm new to this, hence confusion.

Comment: Please check my answer with screenshots, command, reference links, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following command with glue image for 3.0, and it does takes me to the jupyter labs, with a console prompt to choose python/pyspark/etc. notebooks.

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 -e DISABLE_SSL="true" --name glue_jupyter amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01 /home/glue_user/jupyter/jupyter_start.sh
```

In the above command, I have removed "d", so that I can see the logs in the console as the docker runs.

[image]

Choose Glue Spark Local (PySpark) under Notebook. You can start developing code in the interactive Jupyter notebook UI.

A notebook with sample code showing spark versions
[image]

Please refer to this AWS document (Jupyter Lab section) for reference:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html

Comment: I'm able to open the notebook within lab. My question is how to open the native notebook url/notebook instead of from within url/lab

Comment: then I guess you can try with docker for glue 1.0: docker run -it -p 8888:8888 --name glue_jupyter amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_1.0.0_image_01 /home/jupyter/jupyter_start.sh.

Comment: I think amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_2.0.0_image_01 or amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01 are built to create Jupyter labs, not sure.